# I am trying to get list of all the authors who have had more than 3 piece of work - DBpedia Sparql

Tags: bigdata, sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso, triplestore

I am trying to get list of all the authors who have had 3 or more piece of work done (in DBpedia).

my example can be run on : http://dbpedia.org/sparql

## base code

```
select (count(?work) as ?totalWork), ?author
Where
{
  ?work dbo:author ?author.
}
GROUP BY ?author
```

I get each authors total amount of piece of work done. But when I try to filter to show only list of author that have more than 3 piece of work. I get error:

I tried HAVING keyword or using FILTER keyword.

**Using Filter**

```
select (count(?work) as ?tw), ?author
Where
{
  ?work dbo:author ?author.
  FILTER (?work > 3).
}
GROUP BY ?author

error: Virtuoso 22023 Error VECDT: SR066: Unsupported case in CONVERT (INTEGER -> IRI_ID)
```

**Using HAVING keyword**

```
select (count(?work) as ?tw), ?author
Where
{
  ?work dbo:author ?author.
}
GROUP BY ?author
HAVING (?tw > 3)

Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable ?tw is used in the result set outside aggregate and not mentioned in GROUP BY clause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `HAVING` is correct, but there is a [limitation in SPARQL with indirectly referring to aggregates](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#sparqlHavingClause).

This one works:

```sql
SELECT (count(?work) as ?tw) ?author
WHERE
{
  ?work dbo:author ?author.
}
GROUP BY ?author
HAVING (count(?work) > 3)
```

Comment: @TallTed Thank's for the reference, I didn't know this. Unfortunately, it doesn't raise an error on http://sparql.org/query-validator.html . I'll talk to the maintainers there.

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING (?tw > 3)` is correct SPARQL.  `HAVING` filters after assignments due to `SELECT`, so `?tw` is visible, and before projection.

```
(prefix ((dbo: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>))
    (project (?tw ?author)
      (filter (> ?tw 3)
        (extend ((?tw ?.0))
          (group (?author) ((?.0 (count ?work)))
            (bgp (triple ?work dbo:author ?author)))))))
```

where `?.0` is the assignment of `count`.

Comment: I tried to run this but It gives an error, I would like to see the result and understand the code. Can someone fix this: Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 0: Only '(' and DISTINCT are allowed after COUNT keyword in SPARQL expression at '?'

Comment: What you say here appears to be in direct contraction to the spec -- ["Note that, due to the logic position in which the HAVING clause is evaluated, expressions projected by the SELECT clause are not visible to the HAVING clause."](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#sparqlHavingClause)