# Find Movie Name Whose star is more than 5 in sparql

Tags: sparql

I have written a nested subquery. But it does not give the right answer.I dont know exact query.Please help anyone.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?x a dbo:Film
  {
    SELECT Count(?y) as ?as WHERE {?x dbo:starring ?y}
  }
  FILTER(?as>5)
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question as written is insufficiently clear, it lacks a [mcve]. See [ask] for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: Seriously?! **"What would be the right answer** and **what do you get**? Why the subquery at all? Why the illegal syntax in the inner query (it must be `SELECT (count(?y) as ?as) WHERE`? Why not `SELECT * WHERE {?x a dbo:Film; dbo:starring ?y FILTER(?as>5)` => *films with more than 5 actors*

Comment: *"FInd Movie Name Whose star is more than 5 in sparql"* -> what is that? Please improve at least the English in the question title...

Comment: I just want to know those movie name whose starring is more than 5.

Comment: What is the exact sparql query ,I am not comfortable with sparql query .Pls Explain.

Comment: May be I am wrong to write sparql query ,but I just want  to know " name those movie which has more than 5 star " what is the corresponding sparql query in DBPEDIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am trying to get list of all the authors who have had more than 3 piece of work - DBpedia Sparql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617385/i-am-trying-to-get-list-of-all-the-authors-who-have-had-more-than-3-piece-of-wor)

Comment: `GROUP BY` + the aggregate function `count` is your friend. Documentation is [online](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates) for free

Comment: SELECT  ?work
WHERE
{
?work a dbo:Film.
?work dbo:starring ?star
}
GROUP BY ?work
HAVING (count(?star) > 3).But this does not give any result .I need a query which include this statement ?x a dbo:Film  also.@AKSW

Comment: In the above-mentioned comments, already they have provided you enough hints. If you still don't get it, try this :     SELECT   (count(?name) as ?starring ) ?link 
 WHERE { 
         ?link a dbo:Film. 
         ?link dbo:starring ?name. 
       }         
         GROUP BY ?link
         HAVING (count(?name) > 5 )