# SPARQL HAVING clause giving syntax error

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to get the authors which have more than 3 books authored from DBPedia using [this](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/) with the below:

```
SELECT ?author (COUNT(*) as ?count) WHERE {?works dbo:author ?author. }

Group by(?author)
ORDER BY DESC (?count)
HAVING (?count > 3)
```

But I am receiving a syntax error and when I remove my HAVING clause the rest works fine, any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: You should post your error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am trying to get list of all the authors who have had more than 3 piece of work - DBpedia Sparql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43617385/i-am-trying-to-get-list-of-all-the-authors-who-have-had-more-than-3-piece-of-wor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error is telling you that "?count is used in the result set outside aggregate" so basically you should be using "aggregated solution" which you can do like this:

```
SELECT ?author (COUNT(*) as ?count) WHERE {?works dbo:author ?author. }    
Group by ?author
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 3)
ORDER BY DESC (?count)
```

You can see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#having) formal syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have: 
`Group by(?author) ORDER BY DESC (?count) HAVING (?count > 3)`
but `HAVING` should come before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Changed to

SELECT ?author (COUNT(*) as ?count) WHERE {?works dbo:author ?author. }

Group by(?author)
HAVING (?count > 3)
ORDER BY DESC (?count)

with no luck

Comment: Sure as below:
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable ?count is used in the result set outside aggregate and not mentioned in GROUP BY clause SPARQL query: #output-format:application/sparql-results+json define input:default-graph-uri PREFIX owl: PREFIX xsd: PREFIX rdfs: PREFIX rdf: PREFIX foaf: PREFIX dc: PREFIX : PREFIX dbpedia2: PREFIX dbpedia: PREFIX skos: SELECT ?author (COUNT(*) as ?count) WHERE {?works dbo:author ?author. } Group by(?author) HAVING (?count > 3) ORDER BY DESC (?count)